# How should a student deal with personal criticisms from an assistant professor?

Tags: career-path, professorship, communication, thesis-committee

I am a PhD student. In the past I have met with an assistant professor for some general advice about my research, both times he has made off the cuff comments on my lack of competence as a researcher and overall career suitability in academia. During my continuation, he made further comments in this area. I prepared for 3 weeks solid for my continuation (or transfer or confirmation, in my case, it's like the defense of the first paper) and it went terribly. I can take constructive criticism and I welcome it, so as to better my paper. However, his behaviour I feel is inappropriate, as the focus should be my paper, and not my personal qualities.

I am not sure what to do, if I should even do anything at all. In general, I consider my PhD progress to be very good, and my supervisor as far as I know shares the same sentiment.

I'm cautious to respond to the  assistant professor, because he tells me I am being defensive, but then I am cautious of being too silent because he tells me I am not contributing enough.

I have not spoken to my supervisor since my continuation or told him about my past encounters with this professor. Do I express my disappointment and confusion in our next meeting, or do I just leave it? I am lost on what to do, and I feel very deflated now.

Comment: Do you need to take any course taught by him? Do you absolutely need him in your committee? Can you try to keep distance from him? I mean, why do you care about his comments that much?

Comment: What is your exact relationship with this professor? If you just went to him for advice and he doesn't have any constructive advice to offer, the best course of action would probably be to simply ignore him. If you somehow depend on him and his opinion (e.g., he is a thesis examiner), that's a different problem.

Comment: @Roland from what I read the "continuation" seems to be an official step in the PhD at that university...This is unclear though. What is a continuation?

Comment: sorry I should have explained, continuation (or transfer or confirmation), in my case, it's like the defense of the first paper

Comment: @Kelly: Please edit the question to clarify what the continuation is. Otherwise people have to read the comments in order to understand the question.

Comment: I still don't understand what a "continuation" is.  Why would a first paper need a defense?  Isn't that what referee reports are for?

Comment: _he has made off the cuff comments on my lack of competence as a researcher and overall career suitability in academia_ — Okay, so he's a childish jerk.  Don't engage; just walk away.  If he's on your thesis committee, kick him off.

Comment: Is "improper" really the correct term for a professor criticizing your competence. Not nice, hurful, sure. But improper seems a bit strong.

Comment: I think it's completely out of bounds, it is unfair to make judgements of my competence based on one working paper. The focus should be on my paper (which he was reading for the first time during the actual continuation interview), and not my future endeavours. Unless I ask for career advice, I should be left to evaluate myself. Furthermore, this assistant professors research area is different to mine.

Comment: I'll leave this for others to answer, but given that he is an assistant professor, others may be more willing to listen to complaints about him since he is not yet tenured (I assume).

Comment: It wasn't clear that this was an assistant professor. This adds another slant to the situation. An assistant professor has still to fight for their place in the pack, so that may give us a clue as to the driver of their behaviour. Now as a PhD you are not even close to their "pack hierarchy level", so it's not just inappropriate but actually utterly misdirected for them to take out their dominance display on you. As they are not your boss, you can ignore their put-downs, stay cool and polite (but make sure your supervisor is smartened up enough to not let this person be on your committee!).

Comment: "The focus should be on my paper ... and not my future endeavours."  Surely this rather depends on the purpose of the continuation meeting; if the purpose is to determine whether you have the required qualities (and resources) to successfully complete a PhD, then your research competence is very relevant (and can't be judged solely from one paper).  It could be the purpose of the meeting is to anticipate future problems so that they can be addressed.  I would talk to your supervisor about it, at least to get his/her opinion on your progress/suitability.

Comment: " because he tells me I am being defensive, but then I am cautious of being too silent because he tells me I am not contributing enough. " I suspect there may be a miss-communication here.  I would take "defensive" to mean not that you were talking to much, but that you were resistant to (technical) criticism of your work, and that you should be more keen to talk about the difficulties/flaws/errors in your work.  So talk more, but be more self-critical (which is a key skill in research, which the prof. may be trying to encourage).

Comment: Do speak to you supervisor, he/she will probably have a better idea what the other prof. is trying to do, and at least will be able to give you a clear idea of your true progress/suitability.  Don't be deflated, criticism is something that happens a lot in science and learning to deal with it constructively is a very important skill, it is the critical reviewers of your papers that are your real friends.  When you next have a formal meeting, make sure your supervisor clearly explains the purpose of the meeting, so that you have the right expectations and can prepare accordingly.

Comment: "I consider my PhD progress to be very good, and my supervisor as far as I know shares the same sentiment. " and "I have not spoken to my supervisor since my continuation".  I am rather concerned by this, your supervisor should have met with you soon after the continuation meeting to discuss how it went and to give you formal feedback on how you are progressing (it should be a matter of record, rather than speculation at this stage).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

He may be competing with your supervisor. He may not like your general topic. He may not like you. Or, he really believes what he says. Or he wants to test you. You don't know.

You have to live with people who confuse what's going on with prejudice- or agenda-coloured "truth". Practically all successful researchers have encountered such put-downs.

Schechtman (later Nobel winner) got a "Introduction to Crystallography" book put on his table when he first reported that he got a 5-fold symmetry, hence quasicrystals, in his experiment. Feynman got put-down big time initially by Oppenheimer and was only saved by Dyson's aggressive intervention.

You think your progress is good? Your supervisor does, too? That's enough for you to go on, then. This guy may be a big shot, but for you, it doesn't count. Big shots are usually right when they think something is cool/great. They can be awfully wrong when they think something is not good. Trust your instincts.

Comment: In fact, the famous Linus Pauling (Nobel laureate) was extremely critical of Schechtman's work before it became widely-accepted, and said "There is no such thing as quasicrystals, only quasi-scientists."

Comment: _He may be competing with your supervisor_ - reminds me with this [PhD Movie 2 scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbT4G8XR2io&t=1m2s)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your advice! I think you're right, I guess I have let him get into my head, and have second guessed everything.

Comment: @Kelly Every time I have seen this happening around me (with friends, colleagues, stories from my advisor) it has always been political. This professor and your professor are probably on opposite "political teams" within the department. So making life difficult for the "other" students is one way. Once we actually saw this erupting into a fiasco at a student's master's defense where the other guy showed up and started asking difficult questions to harass the student because he hated the advisor. The chair had to stand up, take charge, and almost threw him out of the room. Ridiculous!

Comment: +1 for "Big shots are usually right when they think something is cool/great. They can be awfully wrong when they think something is not good. "

Comment: @ChrisK We should have a "tweet this" plugin for these great punchlines.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim about Feynman? I don't remember reading something like this in Mehra's biography of him.

Comment: @Danu James Gleick, "Genius". He describes in detail how Oppenheimer (after Manhattan) became very sceptical and was essentially "coerced" by Dyson to listen to Feynman's ideas.

Answer (score 41):

Captain Emacs already gave a great answer, I'd like to address this point specifically:

> I'm cautious to answer back to the professor, because he tells me I am being defensive, but then I am cautious of being too silent, because he tells me I am not contributing enough.

I suggest the following strategy:

- If he criticizes you personally: Ignore it.
- If he criticizes your work: Answer back, but use questions. Don't defend your work, try to find out *why* we criticizes it and what alternatives he suggests. If he is right, you get valuable feedback. If he is wrong (and others are present, like at your continuation), he will make himself look bad rather than you.

Example: *"And you call yourself a scientist? This section is rubbish."*

- Bad answer: (Get angry) "Of course I am a scientist! And this section is great because..."
- Good answer: (Take out a pen and paper to take notes) "Why do you think it is rubbish? How can it be improved?"

> I have not spoken to my supervisor since my continuation or told him about my past encounters with this professor. Do I express my disappointment and confusion in our next meeting, or do I just leave it?

Sure, mention it! Your advisor's job is not only to help you write a great thesis, but also to help you find your way in academia and guide you through the process.

Comment: Downvoted.  Engaging the abuser is really not a good strategy for dealing with abuse.  Better to walk away, cut off all contact with the abuser, and get help from someone you trust.

Comment: @JeffE: Sure. At the risk of sounding defensive (no pun intended): My answer was written under the impression that cutting off all contact is not an option (or incurs too high a cost). In addition, I do believe that being able to deal with difficult employees/customers/colleagues/superiors is a valuable skill which can be learned/trained and greatly enhances your career options. That said, I'd also keep contact with this person to the minimum required.

Comment: I agree that one should minimise contact, but sometimes this is not possible, e.g. in an examination or a work situation. Certainly OP, as a student, cannot simply ignore a professor in the same social context who is ostentatiously giving statements disguised as "objective" (which are, of course, not objective at all, but can be extremely difficult to counter). Keeping nerves, confidence and good manners is therefore paramount to prevail in the long-term; Heinzi gives a workable suggestion, although myself I prefer a tad sharper tack, riposting with something outside the prof's expertise.

Comment: +1 for "If he criticizes you personally: Ignore it.". I would also add, "cut out all the small talk because small talk often reveals personal information and is food for future personal criticism; make your relationship a purely professional one".

Comment: Never ignore a personal criticism. When it comes to us humans, perception is reality. If you appear that you're coming off as a slacker, even if you're not doing anything wrong, you should try to find out *why* you come off that way to them and strongly consider doing something about it. If someone discretely tells you your fly is down at a party, you discretely zip it up. If someone grabs the mic and goes "Heinzi's fly is down, everyone point and laugh!!!!" are you still going to leave it down? Just because someone is a jerk in pointing something out doesn't necessarily mean their wrong.

Comment: @corsiKa Actually, finding the right balance is the point at hand. If they can make you "jump through the hoop" reliably, they simply will not leave you alone. With bullies, if you cannot avoid them, you are better off if you are unpredictable and unprofitable to manipulate.

Comment: _If someone grabs the mic and goes "Heinzi's fly is down, everyone point and laugh!!!!" are you still going to leave it down?_ — Of course not.  But I'm not going to invite them to my next party, either.

Answer (score 4):

Kelly, if you have had a chance to meet with your supervisor since you asked this question, you may not need any further advice.

I'm male, so maybe not qualified to speak to this topic. You call yourself Kelly, which where I am (geographically) is usually but not exclusively female. A male professor is criticizing you personally and telling you that you are not suitable for academia, so it's even more likely that you are female. If I've guessed right on that, then since I see you also used a male pronoun for your supervisor, you should discuss this with women on the faculty in your department.

My other comments are gender neutral.

I'm worried because you said you prepared for three weeks and the exam went badly. If that's just because an assistant professor asked inappropriate questions, that doesn't reflect badly on you. But your supervisor is supposed to intervene for you if something inappropriate happens in an exam, and it sounds like he didn't. If the rudeness was coming from an assistant professor, then your supervisor should be at least of equal rank and it isn't obvious what power dynamic would keep him silent when you were being mistreated.

If the exam did go badly, your supervisor should bring it up without prompting, I think, but I wouldn't count on it. I think you need to know if your supervisor thinks it went badly, and if he shares your view on why it went badly. If you agree that this one assistant professor is the problem, then you supervisor should agree to keep him off your committee in the future, and all is good.

You say you view your PhD progress as very good and "as far as you know" your supervisor shares the same sentiment. I wish you were more confident in that. Maybe you and your supervisor need to agree on milestones and deadlines to reach the milestones so you can judge that you are making good progress.

It's 99.9% likely the other professor is wrong in his assessment of you. But you're probably not the next Feynman or the next Marie Curie, because they wouldn't need to ask the question you've asked. They succeeded no matter what anyone else said. The rest of us might be suitable for academia but still slip through the cracks without support from mentors and colleagues. In your question I see red flags that say your supervisor isn't supporting you.

Comment: What the heck? After being oh-so-careful not to gender-judge ("Kelly"...female name), you say, with a straight face, and to applause of 2 upvoters "A male professor is criticizing you personally and telling you that you are not suitable for academia, so it's even more likely that you are female." Seriously bigoted, dude (which, where I'm from, can refer to a man or woman); I find this self-satisfied statement insulting. It's good that you estimated the precise likelihood of the other professor being wrong ("99.9%") though. Big downvote.

Comment: @gnometorule As sexism is sadly quite common in academia, particularly in STEM disciplines, it's not entirely improbable, that this personal criticism is a demonstration of that, though I wouldn't up the probability in such strong terms as "even more likely".

Comment: "In your question I see red flags that say your supervisor isn't supporting you." +1

Comment: @LLlAMnYP: The question asked has just the right amount of obfuscation that what happened is consistent with both hearing "That's why a girl shouldn't do research!", and, after witnessing incompetence in statistics, "You don't understand statistics!"; and that's probably quite consciously so, to attract the crowd of the professionally offended (like this answer-writer) to receive a pet on the back; note also the strange editing in of "assistant" as if that mattered. In the much more likely case this was about pointing out a lack like that, it takes being part of the cult to scream 'sexism!'.

Comment: @gnometorule At the risk of sounding stupid, I have to admit, that I'm having trouble understanding your comment. Although English is almost a mother-tongue to me (grew up in Britain, but not from there), I'd have to ask you to rephrase what you said. No offence meant, in case the gist of my reply suggests otherwise.

Comment: @gnometorule Re:editing in `assistant`, Captain Emacs mentioned in the comments under the OP, that the fact that he's an "assistant" may be particularly relevant to the question, prompting the editing.

Comment: Hanlon's razor is useful in situations like this, or at least more mildly worded versions of it, i.e. assume the meaning that casts the writer in the best light consistent with what was written, rather than assuming the worst.  Of course that doesn't mean you shouldn't point out that it is ambiguously worded and needs clarification, it certainly is.

Comment: I did speak to my supervisor. I am more confused! He explained that his bad behaviour was out of caring for my future, he also said I should not worry about it because academics are weird communicators so these things happen. surprisingly, he thought the continuation went well.  I still think there's more to the professors behaviour. In the end, I said my piece and I am happy I explained myself. I will be more cautious in the future when it comes to interactions with staff. But I have to disagree with your comment, my supervisor is extremely supportive, more so than is expected I think.

Comment: @gnometorule Is it bigoted of me to believe what I read in APS (American Physical Society) News that half of the undergraduate women at the APS Conference on Undergrad Women In Physics say they have received some form of sexual harassment or inappropriate comments in the field? Is it bigoted of me to believe a female graduate student in my group who said that our PI had made reference to her sex/gender when he was criticizing her performance? Or are you just the type of person who cries foul every time someone acknowledges there might be sexism to get the pat on the back from your own cult?

Comment: @Anonymous; Ooooooh - a true believer! I bow in shame, facing a human being on a much higher moral plane than I could ever dare to hope to be part of...also, what is my cult?

Comment: @gnometorule just to be clear, you're telling me that the graduate student I referred to in my research group, who you don't actually know, was lying about what a professor in my department said to her, is that right? I mean my small brain can't figure out why else you would mockingly call me a true believer except to say that I'm gullible. Your cult? I assume it's the cult of Donald Trump and/or the Republican Party of the US.